# What do they mean by “I’m good either night”

Tags: either-or

Let me know if Thursday or Friday for Miami spice works or not.

“I’m good either night”

Comment: The underlying idea is "I can participate in the specified activity on either night."

Answer (score 1):

This is an informal usage of "good", common in American English but less so in British usage (although increasing in use). In this context, it means "available" or "comfortable with".

[Good (Merriam-Webster definition)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good)

> **1b (5)** : that can be relied on
>
> - good for another year
> - good for a hundred dollars
> - always good for a laugh

Note that in conversational (informal) English, **context is everything**! Another of M-W's definitions looks superficially relevant, but in fact would indicate exactly the *opposite* meaning, i.e. "No, I *don't* want to go out either night":

> **1h *informal*** : having everything desired or required : content and not
>   wanting or needing to do anything further
>
> - "Do you want anything else to drink?" "No thanks, I'm good."
> - "I have had girlfriends say, 'Hey, you wanna go walking?' And I'm just not interested. I'm like 'Uh, no, I'm good.' But they keep inviting me!"    —Laila Ali

Any ambiguity between these two meanings of "good" could be reduced by saying "*Yes*, I'm good" (acceptance), whereas "No, I'm good" would usually mean rejection but could also just be a poorly expressed acceptance.